# Can't understand logic behind review answer.

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

Sorry about the title, wasn't sure how to make it more descriptive of my question. I'm doing unit review right now, and looked at the online posted review answers by our teacher. I understand the math and reasoning of everything except for two lines, they are:

$$0= \frac{2\pi}{3}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{30}t\right)$$
$$\cos \frac\pi2 = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{30}t\right)$$

Nothing changes except for "2π/3cos" moving to the other side of the equation and becoming "cos π/2", are there steps here that aren't shown?

Comment: Two things are happening: (1) both sides are being multiplied by $\frac{3}{2\pi}$ (this doesn't change the left side since it's zero), and (2) $\cos\frac\pi2$ is being substituted for $0$ (which is fine because zero is the value of $\cos\frac\pi2$.)

Comment: Oh wow, I can't even believe I missed that. I guess I looked at it and got confused with the fact it didnt look equivalent and didnt think to check  (2)cosπ/2. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If $$0= \frac{2\pi}{3}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{30}t\right)$$
then
$$0= \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{30}t\right)$$
(since $\frac{2\pi}{3}\neq 0$). But as $\cos\frac{\pi}{2}=0$, you can rewrite it as 
$$\cos\frac{\pi}{2}= \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{30}t\right)$$